# Get web url for requested jsp page

Tags: jsp

I request for page, http://192.168.11.212:25/TespApp/pages/login.jsp

with request.getContextPath(), we can get path "/TespApp"

but i want to get full url for the web-config directory i.e. http://192.168.11.212:25/TespApp

Is there any variable to get that url in jsp

Comment: http://192.168.11.212:25/TespApp..waht is TespApp ? context path? then why does getContextPath() gives "/TespApp/pages"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the full path, try something like:

```
    if ((request.getServerPort() == 80) || (request.getServerPort() == 443))
    {
        return request.getScheme() + "://" +
                request.getServerName() +
                request.getContextPath();
    }
    else
    {
        return request.getScheme() + "://" +
                request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() +
                request.getContextPath();
    }
```

Comment: but when i deploy it to DNS server i can't get the port :) than...I have to again change the code..

Comment: The request still has a port. For example, http://www.stackoverflow.com:80 is the same as http://www.stackoverflow.com. The browser just assumes port 80.